# How to update database with delphi XE8 firemonkey project?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have a firemonkey multi device project for iOS and Android. I use a SQLite database to store my data. I deploy the database through adding the file in project deployment and setting the remote path.

Right now if I make any changed to my database and then update my app the old database stays. Only if delete the app and reinstall it i get the new database or if i delete the app data i get the new database.

But I want to update the database with new tables/colomns/inserts without losing any data inside the old database.

How do i do this?

Comment: The usual way on Android is to use [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), indicate the schema version in the manifest and to provide upgrade SQL scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a class that checks the current version of the database and the last version. If it's not up to date it will run the update queries runtime.

Comment: How do you check database version? Some specific table? Or Metadata?

Comment: Due to the comment of mjn I searched for the schema version. Then in the documentation I found you could use pragma user_version for this: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version
So no need for custom table if you don't want to. Remark: user_version is integer so no fancy version number format

Comment: @ArieKanarie I created my own table so I can use a more elaborate version numbering and also added a description of the update

Answer (score -1):

I know 2 methods.

First, you can kill old database and unpack and copy new. Demo sample here 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwEZB8sRo0DSakRlU2NZRXRHREE/edit?pli=1

It works for android device.

Second, I think you have to add new fields through SQL code.

Comment: The question asks for a way without losing any data, so answer 1 os wrong, answer to is correct

Comment: I've tried to use the demo sample but it's in russian and also doesn't work.

Comment: You can use 1 way through coping new database  to new file name, copy data and rename it. This is not good way but way.